# Error installing holidays gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, redmine-plugins

I'm receiving the following error when trying to install the holidays gem:

```
# gem install holidays
Fetching: holidays-1.0.4.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing holidays:
        holidays requires holidays (>= 0)
```

I'm not a ruby guy, just installing some deps for [Redmine Backlogs](http://www.redminebacklogs.net/en/installation/) plugin.

Versions and environment:

```
# gem -v
1.8.10

# ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i386-linux]

CentOS Linux release 6.0 (Final)
# uname -r
2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.i686
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The latest version of the gem 1.0.4 seems to require that you have a previous version of the gem so do this and you should be good

```
gem install holidays --version 1.0.3
gem install holidays
```

Now you should have the latest version of the holidays gem

**UPDATE: The author *Alex Dunae* has now fixed this problem**

Comment: Thank you! I've been in the gem page (http://code.dunae.ca/holidays/) but I can't find any reason for the behavior you described, can you explain it to the community and therefor to me.

Comment: I can't explain it either so I've opened an issue for it on Github [https://github.com/alexdunae/holidays/issues/13]

Answer (score 5):

Gem author here -- this is finally fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems 1.0.4 is broken. 1.0.3 installs nicely - try `gem install holidays -v 1.0.3`